# Problems with a simple shell script

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I've faced with the problem of using simple shell commands like AWK and print within my sh scripts on my Mac ( the same script works perfect on the Linux). For instance below script which seek for the columns within given input files didn't works

```
 #! /usr/bin/env bash
input=/Users/Own/Documents/Science/mmgbsa_results/All_decomp2/logs
output=/Users/Own/Documents/Science/mmgbsa_results/All_decomp2/out

for file in $input/*; do
title=$(basename "$file")
#print $title
awk -F’[|]’ '{print $1,$NF}' $file > ${output}/$title
done
```

output:

```
awk: no program given

analysis.sh: line 11: ]’: command not found
awk: no program given

analysis.sh: line 11: ]’: command not found
awk: no program given

analysis.sh: line 11: ]’: command not found
awk: no program given

analysis.sh: line 11: ]’: command not found
awk: no program given

analysis.sh: line 11: ]’: command not found
awk: no program given
```

Here some tests of the shell:

```
Glebs-MacBook-Pro:All_decomp2 Own$ echo $PATH
/Users/Own/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
Glebs-MacBook-Pro:All_decomp2 Own$ awk
usage: awk [-F fs] [-v var=value] [-f progfile | 'prog'] [file ...]
Glebs-MacBook-Pro:All_decomp2 Own$ peint
-bash: peint: command not found
```

Comment: What is peint? Can you run an example awk command on one line - Note Linux uses gnu awk and OS X BSD awk so there could be a difference there - also what is line 11?

Comment: Could you post your `$PATH`? I tested, and your script works, so, the problem seems to be that can reach `awk` command. A quick fix can be append the path to the `awk`, using `/usr/bin/awk` instead.

Comment: actually it was Print which has not been worked (

Comment: Your quotes after the -F in the awk command are wrong, they need to be `'`

Comment: 0942v8653 has the right idea. Make sure you're using a text editor to write your scripts, not a word processor.